# 'Open Project' has encountered an error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

The project description file (.project) for 'AutoClicker' is missing.  This file contains important information about the project.  The project will not function properly until this file is restored.

[image]

I had moved computers in class and moved all my projects on a 1TB hard drive over to the new computer and I had gotten all the projects to work, but one. I have no idea how to fix it, I feel like the path to the file is wrong, but I don't see anything wrong with it.
If anyone has any idea on how to fix this error, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: and do you have `.project` file in the folder with project?

Comment: Okay, for some reason all the files aren't even there anymore. i'm going to try to find them. no idea what happened unless someone deleted them on accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you have lost the `.project` file during the transaction process.

Not really an elegant solution, but what you could do is create a new project in Eclipse and copy the files from your storage to the newly created project (which would have the `.project` file).

Answer (score 3):

Delete your .project file in root project and in your subprojects, then right click on project folder -> delete (not deleting it from disk).
Reimport your project, then, be happy!

Comment: This works for me. So this is an Eclipse bug. Somehow it cannot find an existing .project file.

Answer (score 1):

1) The solution for me, is to delette projet from eclipse ( important no delette content from disk).
2) Import the project
It's OK form me
I hope help U

Answer (score 0):

If the .project file is in the expected location, try checking the case. On case sensitive systems (not Windows) a difference in case between the project name and the folder name may be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error after stash your changes with checking include untracked files then you have to follow below steps to solve the issue.

1. Go to your project root folder.
2. run `git stash list`. You will see your stash changes with given name.
3. Now apply those stash changes by running `git stash apply stash@{0}` where **stash@{0}** is having your stash changes.
4. Now you will be able to open your project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A thing that worked with me (having tortoise) was deleting the .project file then importing it again